# Define base10 RGB alpha channel for Racket 2htdp/world

Tags: racket

I have an image pulled from a tileset that I am using in a Racket 2htdp/world program.

I can grab the tile I want, but the background is not an enumerated name, like blue. I want the "hollow" pixels to be the same color as the background without editing the tileset with an image editor.

Is there a way to make color in the image transparent by specifying the RGB value?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the "hollow" pixels to be the same color as the background

Then you need to use mask as transparent can be both transparent and in background color.

Comment: I found this, but I was womdering if somewhere in the docs for place-image there is a command. https://lists.racket-lang.org/users/archive/2010-December/043552.html

Comment: This is a small riff in the edx.org course "How to Code Simple Data", specifically the design project for section 3b, compund data. So, the rubric restricts the answer/program to the "scope of the course". I interpreted this to mean that anything in 2htdp and BSL was fair game, but requiring "image" would be outside scope. I am pretty proud I was able to get two tiles from a tileset, edit and use a sprite, move it and animate it. It would be fine if I could set the background to 0 8 255 to make it look better.